# How to select a value from a combo box using itextsharp in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a fill-able pdf which has a combo box and the values in it.How can i select a single value programmatically using c# and itextSharp?

Answer (score 3):

You just set the value like any other form field. You can either set an option by value or by name. If you have a combo box called `cbo1` with these three options:

```
-------------------
|Name     | Value |
-------------------
|Option 1 | 1     |
|Option 2 | 2     |
|Option 3 | 3     |
-------------------
```

You can use this to set the value:

```
        //Open the existing PDF
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("Test.pdf");
        //Create the output PDF
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream("Test-Output.pdf", FileMode.Create));

        //Get access to the PDF's form fields
        AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

        //Select by option's name
        pdfFormFields.SetField("cbo1", "Option 3");

        //- OR -

        //Select by option's value
        pdfFormFields.SetField("cbo1", "3");

        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
        pdfStamper.Close();

        pdfReader.Close();
```